# two inches by two inches

Tags: prepositions

> After the article came out, Shields said he asked for an independent
>   investigation, which ultimately exonerated him. He also reached an
>   out-of-court settlement with the newspaper ahead of a lawsuit.
>
> He said the Globe and Mail published a retraction: "**It was about two
>   inches by two inches.**"

[Laura Robinson made false accusation](http://www.cbc.ca/news/canada/british-columbia/laura-robinson-made-false-accusation-of-racism-says-ex-national-coach-1.3124931)

What does "two inches by two inches" mean?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would refer to the size of the article in the newspaper being very small. Newspaper articles are traditionally in a column format which can look like a box, so a two inch by two inch column is very short.

Comment: So it means that the Globe and Mail published a very short retraction announcement ?

Comment: yes, sorry that is what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

I'm gonna add a little bit to Mel's answer.

It's not just saying that they posted a very short retraction announcement, it's specifying exactly how large the column was. "A by B" is a common way to say "A tall and B wide."  So two inches by two inches means that the column was two inches wide and two inches tall. (4 square inches)